# Get only products which are in stock

Tags: stock, out-of-stock, stock-status

I have changed option in Magento to show only products which are in stock. Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventury. DISPLAY OUT OF STOCK PRODUCTS is set to "NO"

On my front/index page I use bellow code to display randomly 5 products from same category.

```
<?php 
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
'qty', 
'cataloginventory/stock_item', 
'qty', 
'product_id=entity_id', 
'{{table}}.stock_id=1', 
'left' 
);
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price', 'special_price' , 'RegularPrice' )); 
$products->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left' );
$products->getSelect()->limit(5);
$products->getSelect()->order('RAND()'); 
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(5))); 
$this->_reviewsHelperBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper'); 
foreach ($products as $product)  : 
?>
```

Above code displays products which are in stock and products which are out of stock.

What I would like to accomplish is to display products which are only in stock. I have tried to do this in so many different ways but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy
the stock information is managed by the cataloginventory module, try to add the following code on your products collection

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

regards

Comment: I try adding code you provided. I received the following error:
  Fatal error: Call to a member function joinField() on a non-object in httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock.php on line 197

Comment: actually this works. My bad.